# How to format a table of numbers with varying decimal points

Tags: dataset, output-formatting

Given:

```
mat1 = {{"", "", X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6}, {reg1, count1, 
12345.6786546, 0.9714322786600009, 0.39860039818934734, 
0.426662162330312, 1.792374088961013, 0.4140144436761481}, {reg2, 
count2, 12345.16786546, 0.9889249587288553, 1.780535580027618, 
1.60781000579517, 0.577725163636736, 0.1175474621597238}, {reg3, 
count3, 12345.0786546, 1.824433941221109, 0.3126457769687216, 
0.357252998031583, 0.961893471647981, 1.510169721094909}, {reg4, 
count4, 12345.26786546, 0.576753111943114, 0.1973429756544189, 
1.52173753847146, 1.901889363592111, 0.61061606981908}, {reg5, 
count5, 12345.976786546, 1.27977000137376, 1.613078010044809, 
1.992528170481412, 1.28320604946023, 1.974675522449778}};

NumberForm[TableForm[mat1], {7, 4}]
```

Generates:

[image]

Touring the past questions, I could not really find an answer to my question. (@BobHanlon shows a way to use `NumberForm` for individual variables, though. It does not work in my case.)

Is there any way to use `NumberForm` for individual columns, for example, `X1`, and delete all the digits in column `X1`?

Is there any way to use `NumberForm` after creating a `Dataset`?

**EDIT**
The rule I like to apply is: if the number concerned in `TableForm` is greater than 1, then drop the digits if any; and if the number is less than 1, keep, say, 3 or 4 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TableForm[Map[If[NumericQ[#], If[# > 1, Floor @ #, Round[#, .001]], #] &, mat1, {-1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
mat1 = {{"", "", X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6}, {reg1, count1, 
    12345.6786546, 0.9714322786600009, 0.39860039818934734, 
    0.426662162330312, 1.792374088961013, 0.4140144436761481}, {reg2, 
    count2, 12345.16786546, 0.9889249587288553, 1.780535580027618, 
    1.60781000579517, 0.577725163636736, 0.1175474621597238}, {reg3, 
    count3, 12345.0786546, 1.824433941221109, 0.3126457769687216, 
    0.357252998031583, 0.961893471647981, 1.510169721094909}, {reg4, 
    count4, 12345.26786546, 0.576753111943114, 0.1973429756544189, 
    1.52173753847146, 1.901889363592111, 0.61061606981908}, {reg5, 
    count5, 12345.976786546, 1.27977000137376, 1.613078010044809, 
    1.992528170481412, 1.28320604946023, 1.974675522449778}};

nbrForm[x_] := Module[{log = Floor@Log10@x},
  NumberForm[x, {5, Min[4, 4 - log]},
   NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}]]

TableForm[mat1 /. x_Real :> nbrForm[x],
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your `code` using my actual table, and it does not work as expected. The reason is that, in my question, for simplicity, I used `X1` in the format given. In the actual table, I have something like `12.02, 367.344, 6754.5676, 3.2, 16549.34` for `X1`. I guess my question was not formulated correctly. The rule I like to apply is: if the number concerned in `TableForm` is greater than 1, then drop the digits if any; and if the number is less than 1, keep, say, 3 or 4 digits. I will edit the question in a moment.

Comment: The revised requested format would seem to ruin the formatting for columns `x2` thru `x6`